# How to made the activity indicator appear immediately in ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm developing a ios app. I use this code on a view, in order to made an activity indicator and a black background appear in place of the whole view while is loading.

```
// hiding all the uioutlet in the view
sfondo.hidden=TRUE;
dalText.hidden=TRUE;
alText.hidden=TRUE;
titoloText.hidden=TRUE;

// generating the activity indicator
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
imgCaricamento = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[imgCaricamento setCenter:CGPointMake(screenWidth/2.0, screenHeight/2.0)]; // I do this because I'm in landscape mode
[self.view addSubview:imgCaricamento]; // spinner is not visible until started
[imgCaricamento startAnimating]; // start!
```

Now the problem is that i launch this code before starting an update and do several things. What happen is that, at the moment this code is launched the view freezes for one-two seconds, only after this delay time, the activity appears. This time it's enough to convey to the user the impression that the app is acting bad... How can i  make this code being executed before and immediately?

Comment: Where exactly do you execute above mentioned code? (Within a view controller? In which method?) Please give a little more information.

Comment: oh, sorry, you're right. Within a view controller in its viewDidAppear. I tried to do it in the viewWillAppear but the delay happened in the calling view, and the problem was even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably doing something that is blocking the main thread, maybe downloading an image, reading something from disk or parsing some data. The main thread is responsible for refreshing the UI and when it is blocked, the UI freezes. You can solve this by doing your processing in the background, on a different thread.

Comment: Sure. The code, that i want to execute after, made a call to an external xml, download an image and so. How do i do the process in background? I tried something like this (enclosing the code in a function beginLoading) [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(beginLoading)
                           withObject:self]; and seem to go well but then i have to execute the specular code to restore the view, that seem to have no effect even i call it in background [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(stopLoading)
                           withObject:self];

Comment: Don't suppose i know what i'm saying. :D The code of the perform selector is a copy-paste for me, no more. I don't know so much about this main thread thing, even if i can suppose to understand what is happening, having studied multithreading.

Comment: I think these resources will help you a lot: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html and http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Comment: Thank you, i'll explore this solution with attention!

Comment: The code to solve the problem, just for the posterity is: [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(beginLoading)
                           withObject:self]; followed somewhere by a [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(endLoading)
                                       withObject:nil
                                    waitUntilDone:YES];. BeginLoading and endLoading contain all the operation necessary for displaying and removing the activity indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from something maybe blocking the main thread therefore preventing the UI being updated I would prepare the `UIActivityIndicatorView` within `viewWillAppear` and execute `[imgCaricamento startAnimating];` within `viewDidAppear` or where ever you start the updating process.

Comment: not bad! it works a bit better... I do some tests, even if i want to explore the main thread thing suggested by Johannes Fahrenkrug, too

Comment: seems to work for now! thank you! :) Anyway i think it's a solution that maybe cause problems in certain condition. Only for this reason, i think, the real answer is what suggest by johannes.